# Help identify please .. fruit in south of France

Tags: identification, fruits, soft-fruit

[image: Picked in south of France .. about 2 inches long. Sweet smelling. Any ideas?]

[image: Picked in south of France .. about 2 inches long. Sweet smelling. Any ideas?]

Picked in south of France .. about 2 inches long. Sweet smelling. Any ideas?

Comment: You wouldn’t happen to have photos of the plant they came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on two comments, this could be [feijoa](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feijoa_sellowiana).

Native to South America, it’s been since grown around the world both as ornamental plant and for their fruit.

*Disclaimer:*
As for all identification requests where the answers claim that a plant is edible, always double check yourself using multiple sources and paying attention to possible doppelgängers before consuming them.

Comment: Concur. This is feijoa (also known as pineapple guava). It is commonly planted in landscaping where I used to live in California. It has an interesting pineapple / mint flavour in my opinion. I have harvested these fruits many times.